# Two store views in DB, use only 1 store view

Tags: magento-1.9, store-view

In our DB we find two store views with id 0 and id 1.
But in the backend we only have 1 store view and we also use only 1 store view, with id 0.

Is this right or are we missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For backend magento use store view id 0
For frontend magento use store view id 1

That's why you have 2 store view in database. It's default magento entry.